# Cookie extraction from jUnit Request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

everyone, I need to go over a 'single sign on' Login that requires user in browser interaction. I cannot just log in programmable, I need to go in the browser and enter credentials.
For this part I manage to go over using jUnit Request with selenium and java. I put in a setUp Thead Group. Now I need to extract the cookie and pass it to other Thread groups and this seems to be a problem.

I have used a BeanShell PreProcessor script to extract the Cookie and it is working with a standard HTTP Request.

BeanShell Post Processor Script here:

`import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;`
`import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;`
`import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.PropertyIterator;`
`import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.JMeterProperty;`
`CookieManager manager = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getCookieManager();`
`PropertyIterator iter = manager.getCookies().iterator();`
`while (iter.hasNext()) {`
`JMeterProperty prop = iter.next();`
`Cookie cookie = prop.getObjectValue();`
`if (cookie.getName().equals(".AspNetCore.Cookies")) {                       props.put("MySessionCookie", cookie);`
`break;`
`}`
`}`

I use the BeanShell PreProcess with this script to pass the Cookie to another Thread Group and it seems to be working on Forms type Authentication:

`import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;`

`import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;`

`CookieManager manager = sampler.getCookieManager();`

`manager.add(props.get("MySessionCookie"));`

Unfortunately this is not working when in the setUp Thread group I use jUnit Request. Can someone assisst on this problem, please?

Answer (score 0):

JUnit Request sampler doesn't have HTTP Cookie Manager, you need to [extract the required cookie from WebDriver instance](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Options.html#deleteCookieNamed(java.lang.String)), construct the [JMeter cookie](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Options.html#deleteCookieNamed(java.lang.String)) from it and save it to JMeter Properties.

Example code:

```
org.openqa.selenium.Cookie seleniumCookie = driver.manage().getCookieNamed(".AspNetCore.Cookies");


org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie jmeterCookie = new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie();

jmeterCookie.setDomain(seleniumCookie.getDomain());
jmeterCookie.setPath(seleniumCookie.getPath());
jmeterCookie.setExpires(seleniumCookie.getExpiry().getTime());
jmeterCookie.setSecure(seleniumCookie.isSecure());

org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext().getProperties().put("MySessionCookie", jmeterCookie);
```

Once done you should be able to access it in another Thread Group

Also be informed that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so it worth considering migrating. More information: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

And last but not the least I don't think you need browser at all, it should be possible to authenticate using JMeter only, it's just a matter of proper [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of the dynamic parameters.